# How to change width size of Jpanels in BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have main JPanel which is Borderlayout with added 4 JPANELS: NORTH(Green), WEST(Red), CENTER(Gray), SOUTH(Blue). I want to reduce width size of WEST(Red) Jpanel, or increase width size of Center(Grey) Jpanel.

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/at5GA.png]

Here is my code:

```
    frame = new JFrame("FreshPos baza podataka");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    // Main paneel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();        
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10) );
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    //West panel;
    JPanel panelWest = new JPanel(new GridLayout(14,0,0,2));
    panelWest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));    
    panelWest.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100,0,0,0) );
    panel.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panelWest.setBackground(Color.red);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TABLES; i++) {          
        buttonsTables[i] = new JButton(tables[i]);          
        buttonsTables[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, buttonsTables[i].getMinimumSize().height));
        panelWest.add(buttonsTables[i]);            
        panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));         
    }       

    //South panel;
    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(); // Donji layout za dugmice    
    southPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,0,0,0) );
    panel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
    southPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    JButton buttonDodaj = new JButton("Dodaj");
    southPanel.add(buttonDodaj);        
    JButton buttonIzmeni = new JButton("Izmeni");
    southPanel.add(buttonIzmeni);       
    JButton butonObrisi = new JButton("Obrisi");
    southPanel.add(butonObrisi);

    //North panel;      
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(); // Donji layout za dugmice
    northPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,10,0,0) );
    panel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    northPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

    JButton buttonImport = new JButton("Importuj fajl");
    buttonImport.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            importActionPerformed(evt);
        }           
    });
    northPanel.add(buttonImport, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JButton ButtonRecord = new JButton("Snimi fajl");
    northPanel.add(ButtonRecord, BorderLayout.WEST);

    // Central panel        
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    panel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to reduce width size of WEST(Red) Jpanel

```
panelWest.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100,0,0,0) );
```

So why is the width of your Border so large?

A Border is for "extra" space around the components.

So the width of your panel is the width of the buttons plus the width of the border.

Edit:

> panelWest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

Don't hardcode a preferred size. The layout manager will calculate the size based on the above logic. Get rid of that statement.

Edit 2:

```
// buttonsTables[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, buttonsTables[i].getMinimumSize().height));
```

Get rid of any logic that attempts to control the size of a component. The point of using layout managers is to let the layout manager do the size calcualtions.

So for your buttons panel you need to nest panels to prevent the buttons from taking all the space.

You can do something like:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add(buttonsPanel);
...
//panel.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which will respect the preferred size of any component added to it.

Another option is to use a GridBagLayout with the wrapper panel. By default the panel will then be displayed in the "center" of the available space. So it will be vertically centered and you won't need the EmptyBorder.

Comment: when i comment that line elements just start from top of screen on y axis..

Comment: @NikolaBozic, Ok, I got the order of the parameters mixed up. see edit.

Comment: yes i tried something with panelWest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));, that is unnecessary.m even without that line west jpanel is still to whide

Comment: //panelWest.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10)); , this line made problem, but thanks for help mister, i will check your answer as correct.